# What is the best resource for learning the features and benefits of windbg?

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg

What is the best resource for learning  the features and benefits of windbg? I want to be able to discuss investigate memory issues (handles, objects), performance issues, etc . . .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are some I like:

- [Maoni Stephens and Claudio Caldato's article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163528.)
- [Maoni's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/maoni/) (it is not updated recently but it contains a lot of useful material)
- [Tess Fernandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/) has a a LOT of info reguarding windbg check out her video from teched in Barcellona. She also has an article called "[Learning .NET Debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/01/30/learning-net-debugging.aspx)" which will certainly be helpful. I suggest you to subscribe to this blog it is allways full with fresh info about debugging.
- [John Robbins from Wintellect](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/default.aspx) has a column on MSDN magazine called [BUGSLAYER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163322.aspx) so check it out and allso his book [Debugging Microsoft .NET 2.0 Application](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735622027)s has few chapters dedicated just to winDbg
- [Install WinDBG](http://blogs.msdn.com/johan/archive/2007/01/11/how-to-install-windbg-and-get-your-first-memory-dump.aspx)
- Getting Started [Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/johan/archive/2007/11/13/getting-started-with-windbg-part-i.aspx) and [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/johan/archive/2007/11/26/getting-started-with-windbg-part-ii.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Good resources here too!

http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart

Answer (score 1):

Below, I've linked a video on how to use Windbg for ASP.NET applications.  I have no idea why it's in another language for the title, but the video is in English.

[Channel 9 - Windbg and ASP.NET](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/deurell/ASPnet-hanganalys-med-WinDbg-Del-1/)

Answer (score 1):

Check [DumpAnalysis.org](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/) out.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Tess Ferrandez' blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/default.aspx). Very good advice and lots of details. There are excellent labs as well to help you practice your skills.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the [SOS Debugging Extension reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) is very good too!